# Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to run a Selenium Webdriver script in Python to do some basic tasks. I can get the robot to function perfectly when running it through the Selenium IDE inteface (ie: when simply getting the GUI to repeat my actions). However when I export the code as a Python script and try to execute it from the command line, the Firefox browser will open but cannot ever access the starting URL (an error is returned to command line and the program stops). This is happening me regardless of what website etc I am trying to access.

I have included a very basic code here for demonstration purposes. I don't think that I have included the proxy section of the code correctly as the error being returned seems to be generated by the proxy.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

The below code is simply meant to open www.google.ie and search for the word "selenium". For me it opens a blank firefox browser and stops.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

class Testrobot2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        myProxy = "http://149.215.113.110:70"

        proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'ftpProxy': myProxy,
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy':''})

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.ie/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_robot2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/#gs_rn=17&gs_ri=psy-ab&suggest=p&cp=6&gs_id=ix&xhr=t&q=selenium&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=seleni&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.ZGU&fp=7c0d9024de9ac6ab&biw=592&bih=665")
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").send_keys("selenium")

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 74):

Works for me this way (similar to @Amey and @user4642224 code, but shorter a bit):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: this works, thank you. strange that the docs say that you need to use the remote driver.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities' why?

Comment: This answer does not work for me, I get an error "Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion'".

Comment: @Alex Depending on the proxy you're using, just add `prox.socks_version = 5` or `prox.socks_version = 4`. That should clear up the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked absolutely fine for me. I removed prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port" and added prox.https_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

Answer (score 41):

How about something like this

```
PROXY = "149.215.113.110:70"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

# you have to use remote, otherwise you'll have to code it yourself in python to 
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy).

Comment: This answer worked well for me. In case anyone else is trying to do this with Edge, `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.EDGE['proxy']` has no effect because Microsoft Edge currently doesn't have a setting to configure a proxy server (to use Edge with a proxy, you must configure the proxy under the Windows network connection settings).

Comment: For full detailed document, see: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#proxy-json-object

Answer (score 17):

My solution:

```
def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
        print PROXY_PORT
        print PROXY_HOST
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whater_useragent")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Then call in your code:

```
my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT)
```

I had issues with this code because I was passing a string as a port #:

```
 PROXY_PORT="31280"
```

This is important:

```
int("31280")
```

You must pass an integer instead of a string or your firefox profile will not be set to a properly port and connection through proxy will not work.

Comment: Port needs to be converted to int? That would make the Firefox proxy example on the official page wrong: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp In their example, PROXYHOST:PROXYPORT is passed as a string.

Comment: @Pyderman, you're confusing `Proxy()` class with `FirefoxProfile()` class. Using profile preferences you have to pass ip and port separately, and casting `port` to `int()`. In `Proxy()` class you just pass the string containig "IP:PORT", and surely it does the rest of work for you.

Comment: Also firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937472/11351291
@Zyy Answer

Answer (score 14):

It's quite an old post, however, for others, it might still benefit by providing the answer as of today, and yet originally author was extremely close to a working solution.

First of all, the ftpProxy setting is no longer supported at this time and will throw an error

```py
proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': myProxy,
        'ftpProxy': myProxy, # this will throw an error
        'sslProxy': myProxy,
        'noProxy':''})
```

Next, instead of setting the proxy property, you should be using firefox options like so

```py
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': ''})

options = Options()
options.proxy = proxy
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Additionally, don't define the scheme when specifying the proxy, especially if you want to use the same proxy for multiple protocols

```py
myProxy = "149.215.113.110:70"
```

All together it looks like this

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

myProxy = "149.215.113.110:70"
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': ''})

options = Options()
options.proxy = proxy
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.ie")
```

Comment: and in the case of authentication?

Answer (score 9):

Proxy with verification. This is a whole new python script in reference from a  Mykhail Martsyniuk sample script.

```
# Load webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

# Load proxy option
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

# Configure Proxy Option
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL

# Proxy IP & Port
prox.http_proxy = “0.0.0.0:00000”
prox.socks_proxy = “0.0.0.0:00000”
prox.ssl_proxy = “0.0.0.0:00000”

# Configure capabilities 
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

# Configure ChromeOptions
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/share chromedriver',desired_capabilities=capabilities)

# Verify proxy ip
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")
```

Answer (score 8):

Try setting up sock5 proxy too. I was facing the same problem and it is solved by using the socks proxy

```
def install_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        print PROXY_PORT
        print PROXY_HOST
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(PROXY_PORT))  
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Then call 
`install_proxy ( ip , port )`  from your program.

Comment: how would you modify this to accept proxy credentials?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is looking for a solution here's how :

```
from selenium import webdriver
PROXY = "YOUR_PROXY_ADDRESS_HERE"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy']={
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "autodetect":False
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.whatsmyip.org/')
```

Answer (score 6):

The result stated above may be correct, but isn't working with the latest webdriver. 
Here is my solution for the above question. Simple and sweet

```
        http_proxy  = "ip_addr:port"
        https_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy']={
            "httpProxy":http_proxy,
            "sslProxy":https_proxy,
            "proxyType":"MANUAL"
        }

        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

**OR**

```
    http_proxy  = "http://ip:port"
    https_proxy = "https://ip:port"

    proxyDict = {
                    "http"  : http_proxy,
                    "https" : https_proxy,
                }

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxyDict)
```

Answer (score 5):

This helps me in September 2022 - proxy for selenium with Auth user+password

```
import os
import zipfile

from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = '192.168.3.2'  # rotating proxy or host
PROXY_PORT = 8080 # port
PROXY_USER = 'proxy-user' # username
PROXY_PASS = 'proxy-password' # password

manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)

def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        os.path.join(path, 'chromedriver'),
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    driver.get('https://ifconfig.me/)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[source link](https://medium.com/@itsmnthn/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python-42bc068d6bd)

Answer (score 4):

Try by Setting up FirefoxProfile

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


"Define Both ProxyHost and ProxyPort as String"
ProxyHost = "54.84.95.51" 
ProxyPort = "8083"



def ChangeProxy(ProxyHost ,ProxyPort):
    "Define Firefox Profile with you ProxyHost and ProxyPort"
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", ProxyHost )
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(ProxyPort))
    profile.update_preferences()
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


def FixProxy():
    ""Reset Firefox Profile""
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 0)
    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)


driver = ChangeProxy(ProxyHost ,ProxyPort)
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")

time.sleep(5)

driver = FixProxy()
driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

This program **tested** on both Windows 8 and Mac OSX. If you are using Mac OSX and if you don't have selenium updated then you may face `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException`. If so, then try again after upgrading your selenium

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers above and on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988821/running-selenium-behind-a-proxy-server) either didn't work for me with Selenium 3.14  and Firefox 68.9 on Linux, or are unnecessarily complex. I needed to use a WPAD configuration, sometimes behind a proxy (on a VPN), and sometimes not. After studying the code a bit, I came up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

proxy = Proxy({'proxyAutoconfigUrl': 'http://wpad/wpad.dat'})
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

The Proxy initialization sets proxyType to ProxyType.PAC (autoconfiguration from a URL) as a side-effect.

It also worked with Firefox's autodetect, using:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType

proxy = Proxy({'proxyType': ProxyType.AUTODETECT})
```

But I don't think this would work with both internal URLs (not proxied) and external (proxied) the way WPAD does. Similar proxy settings should work for manual configuration as well. The possible proxy settings can be seen in the code [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/common/proxy.html).

Note that directly passing the Proxy object as `proxy=proxy` to the driver does NOT work--it's accepted but ignored (there should be a deprecation warning, but in my case I think Behave is swallowing it).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and allow to use an headless browser,  you just need to call the method passing your proxy.

```
def setProxy(proxy):
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        #options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        prox = Proxy()
        prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
        prox.http_proxy = proxy
        prox.ssl_proxy = proxy
        capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
        return webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

Answer (score 3):

Surprised to see no examples of using authenticated proxies.

**October 2022 solution for authenticated proxies (Firefox & Chrome):**

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "0.0.0.0";
PROXY_PORT = "0000"
PROXY_USERNAME = "user"
PROXY_PASS = "pass"

# If you're using Firefox
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST) 
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT) 
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.no_proxies_on', 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')
credentials = '%s:%s' % (PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASS)
credentials = b64encode(credentials.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')
fp.set_preference('extensions.closeproxyauth.authtoken', credentials)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

# If you're using Chrome
chrome_options = WebDriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s:%s@%s:%s' % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASS))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Proxied request
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s:%s@%s:%s' % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASS))` the username & password should appear before the hostname

Comment: Also, the chrome arguements doesn't work. Chrome cannot handle proxy authentication via arguments, the above code results in `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES` error on chrome

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Dugini, some [config entries](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) have been removed. Maximal:

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":[],
    "proxyType":"MANUAL"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Scraping the data from any online source is quite easy when scraping APIs are used. You can try using scraper API to scrape the information from webpages and it automatically parses the web data. API can be integrated into your source code as well. Other than using API to scrape data, you can try the under-mentioned source code in beautiful soup to scrape data using CSS selectors. Before trying this code, please note that the select() method can be utilized to find numerous elements. Along with that, select_one() to be used search single element.

> Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
PROXY = "177.46.141.143:59393" #your proxy  (ip address: port no)
chrome_options = WebDriverWait.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("https://www.ipchicken.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

**January 2023 solution with authentication and SSL for Firefox**

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = "ip"
PROXY_PORT = "port"
PROXY_USERNAME = "username"
PROXY_PASS = "password"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', int(PROXY_PORT))
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.no_proxies_on", 'localhost, 127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username", PROXY_USERNAME)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password", PROXY_PASS)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("https://2ip.ru")
```

Also there is a possibility you might need to lock in your ip address in proxy provider account settings. Otherwise you will be prompt to enter credentials on page load.

Answer (score 0):

**Authenticated proxy support. September 2023**

I know of **2** ways to support *authenticated* proxies in selenium. I will showcase both.

**Method 1:** *selenium-wire*

If you're willing to download another library, which extends the base selenium library. Authenticated proxy support can be added via the [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) library.

It should be noted, using this method will cause the browser to state the connection is 'unsecure' as seleniumwire uses it's own root certificate to intercept requests. It is possible to download seleniumwire's certificate and prevent this, however for this example i will not do that and will instead choose to ignore the unsecured warning. If this is not ideal, and you do not wish to download the root certificiate, see method 2. See [here](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#certificates) for more information regarding seleniumwire's certificate handling.

See the code below for an implementation utilising the *selenium-wire* library.

```python
from seleniumwire import webdriver

proxy_host = "your_host"
proxy_port = 8888
proxy_user = "your_username"
proxy_pass = "your_password"

seleniumwire_options = {
    "proxy":{
        "http":f"http://{proxy_user}:{proxy_pass}@{proxy_host}:{proxy_port}",
        "verify_ssl":False,
    }
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') #ignore the 'unsecured' warning caused by seleniumwires root certificate (if certificate is not installed)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=chrome_options,
    seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
)

driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
input()
driver.quit()
```

**Method 2:** *Chrome-extension*

Another way to use a proxy in selenium is by using a chrome extension that automatically loads the proxy to chrome, and authenticates it with the relative auth credentials when requested.

I will use a chrome extension, similar to that posed by @Jackssn , but rewritten to support manifest v3; as v2 has become deprecated in 2023.

See the code below:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

## js strings to be written to file when creating chrome extension

ext_json_manifest = """{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Proxy Loader",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background":{
        "service_worker":"service-worker.js"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "proxy",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestAuthProvider"
    ],
    "host_permissions":[
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "minimum_chrome_version": "108"
}"""

ext_js_serviceworker = """host = "%s"
port = %s
username = "%s"
password = "%s"


var config = {
    mode:"fixed_servers",
    rules:{
        singleProxy:{
            host:host,
            port:port,
            scheme:"http",
        },
        bypassList:["localhost"] //wont use a proxy for these sites
    }
}

chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    {value:config,scope:"regular"},
    function(){}
)

// supply proxy auth credentials when prompted.
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function(details) { //
        return {
            authCredentials:{
                username:username,
                password:password
            }
        }
    },
    {
        urls:["<all_urls>"] //which urls to provide credentials for
    },
    ["blocking"] //block the request until auth details have been supplied
)"""

## your proxy details
proxy_host = "your_host"
proxy_port = 8888
proxy_user = "your_username"
proxy_pass = "your_password"

## create extension
ext_path = "./extension/"
Path(ext_path).mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)

with open(str(Path(ext_path).joinpath("manifest.json")),"w+") as f:
    f.write(ext_json_manifest)
    f.close()

with open(str(Path(ext_path).joinpath("service-worker.js")),"w+") as f:
    f.write(ext_js_serviceworker % (proxy_host,proxy_port,proxy_user,proxy_pass))
    f.close()

## configure and create driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f"--load-extension={str(Path(ext_path).absolute())}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

## delete extension once loaded.
shutil.rmtree(ext_path)

## check selenium is using the proxy.
driver.get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
input()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -4):

try running tor service, add the following function to your code.

```
def connect_tor(port):

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', port, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def main():

connect_tor()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: This post lacks information, connect_tor() and main() functions have no correct indentation, and connect_tor() call is missing the mandatory argument "port" on the example. Which tor port should I use? Where can I get Tor's port information?

Comment: Tor network (even if adds an extra layer of anonymity) is very slow.