# How to use socks proxy in webdriver's HTMLUNIT?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

the code:

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:%i/wd/hub" % HTMLUNIT_PORT, cap)
```

tried doing this before initializing:

```
...
cap['proxy']['proxyType'] = 'manual'
cap['socksProxy'] = ip + ':' + str(port)
...
```

but it seems it didn't work - the IP remained unchanged.

How can I use socks proxy in webdriver AND htmlunit?

Answer (score 1):

That wasn't easy =(

Finally found it here: [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python)

```
...
caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS
PROXY = '127.0.0.1:9050'
caps['proxy'] = {
    "socksProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=caps)
...
```