# Selenium webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy) not effective

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *

myProxy = "user:pass@proxy:port"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.get('http://whois.urih.com/')
```

When directed to that website it still shows my local proxy. I got the above from the selenium site but it has not availed me.

EDIT: I just tried changing the format to `proxy:port:user:pass` and this time the proxy seems engaged since now the dialog box opened to input username and pass. Well this is no good either. Surely I don't need to try the roundabout way of focusing the alert and inputting the info there...

Comment: I might be wrong, but can it be that httpProxy, ftpProxy, etc supposed to be a host, while username and password should be in socksUsername and socksPassword?

Comment: @KirilS.  You are right, I checked in firefox network configurations and I did not find anything related to proxy user name and password

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the working ways to setup proxy for firefox webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http",ip) #set your ip
firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port) #set your port
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get(url) #target url
```

Comment: While I agree that this is one of the ways to get proxy properly configured for Firefox, calling it a "correct way to setup the proxy for selenium" is incorrect, while the method the OP is using IS correct. For instance using this method you need to have proxy configuration for each browser (IE, Chrome will have different ways to set the proxy on browser level), and potentially you may end up with more branches vor various versions of the browser, if some version changes their internal implementation of proxy...

Comment: How am I supposed to set it up if my proxy fromat is: ip:port:user:pass? It isn't clear. Or alternative formet: user:pass@ip:port

Comment: @KirilS. I agree but I have tried many different ways and this was the only one that reflected on firefox

Comment: @RoryGillum Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python

Comment: Where are username and password supposed to go? That other thread doesn't offer any new information over what is posted above excepting changing port to int.

Comment: @RoryGillum I can't find a way to input the user name and password. if firefox prompts you. Using selenium why don't you insert username then press tab and insert password

Comment: I tried; didn't work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021474/python-why-isnt-this-selenium-alert-send-keys-working