# Python - Why isn't this selenium alert, send keys, working?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
import time

myProxy = "xxx.x.x:yyy"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })
driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
###

alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys('xxxxx')
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform()
ActionChains(driver).send_keys('yyyy')
alert.accept()
```

The dialog appears and pops up but then the project just hangs never inputting any keys. How do I make it fill the dialog fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code instead of `ActionChains`

```
alert.send_keys('xxxxx')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('yyyy')
```

Alternatively you could try the following as well

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys('xxxxx').send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys('yyyy').perform()
alert.accept()
```

`ActionChains` will queue the actions and executes the actions when `perform` is called

You could refer the following link for `ActionChains`
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains