# Change proxy setting in firefox without closing browser selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

*** Before you read below I have seen a similar question asked but as far as I could tell it was posted two years ago and I am getting conflicting data

I am trying to be able to get firefox to use a different proxy every time the current one times out. Unfortunately I have not been able to get this to work without closing firefox. However if I manually change the proxy settings in firefox they take effect without the need to restart the browser.

Has selenium had this functionality added at any point between two years ago and now?

This is what I have to launch firefox with a proxy:

```
proxy = Proxy({
'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
'httpProxy': myProxy,
'ftpProxy': myProxy,
'sslProxy': myProxy,
'noProxy': ''
})
driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
```

I am able to change the value of myProxy out while its running but unfortunatly once it loops it does not take the new value of myProxy.

Comment: I think this will help you. This program is updated and tested. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38168865/5409601