# How to change proxy settings using Python 2.7 in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, selenium, proxy, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver in python scripts. I want to change proxy settings to vpn from python before visiting any website so that when visit any website through webdriver they will detect according to vpn ip address.

Can anybody please help me to do this. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Mac Proxy Settings]

Comment: I solved the issue by changing Firefox Profile settings. It is not doing the exact same thing. But enough for my requirement. You may also try this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38168865/5409601

Answer (score 0):

As you are using python binding, you need to use the remote object to set the proxy.

the other way is to change the python binding code itself.

Following code will change the proxy

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "localhost:8080"

# Create a copy of desired capabilities object.
desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
# Change the proxy properties of that copy.
desired_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

# you have to use remote, otherwise you'll have to code it yourself in python to 
# dynamically changing the system proxy preferences
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)
```

Comment: I got this error in Windows 8.1: `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>` and this error in Mac OSX `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>`

Comment: is selenium grid up and running ?

Comment: no worries. I got the solution from somewhere else. May be documentation on selenium site not up to date. I have written the solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38168865/5409601