# Python with selenium issue (basic issue)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am running selenium on python and I have firefox installed.

When I try to open firefox with selenium I am getting a nasty error. My code is running fine on my main machine (win10) but when I run it on a virtual machine (win7) I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" C:/Users/win7.PC/Desktop/Kijiji/kijiji.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/win7.PC/Desktop/Kijiji/kijiji.py", line 408, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x02963690>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've upgraded python, selenium and I tried with firefox 47, 46 and even 28 :(

I attempted to change the PATH:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")
```

It indicated that 'path' is not a valid input

attempted to change binary path like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Still same issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try executable_path='your file path' not path = 'your file path'

Comment: So that actually did work, but I have a profile setup with proxies and other stuff. It seems to just open my regular default profile instead of a unique instance of firefox with the profile I set up. Any other suggestion? BTW, I also added firefox to the enviromental variables (in PATH) added-    ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python