# Python+Selenium+PhantomJs = Not clicking =( But Firefox clicks

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have a problem:

Here is a code to click the link on the site in Firefox. It works. Clicks.
But the same code in PhantomJS going to a page but not clicks.
Please help solve the problem. thanks in advance

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('http://nnmclub.to')
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'www.marketgid.com')]").click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: How do you know that there there was no click? It's a headless browser. At least you should add `browser.get_screenshot_as_file(path_to_file)` to check whether page changed or not

Comment: I missed this line in the code. I use it. With "browser.get_screenshot" and I know that he is not clicked. Just loaded page, but not completed following the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link that you're trying to click has attribute `target="_blank"` which means that this link should be opened in new tab (window). To see that it actually clicked you should try to switch to that new window with following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser=webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('http://nnmclub.to')
current = browser.window_handles[0]
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'www.marketgid.com')]").click()
time.sleep(10)
newWindow = [window for window in browser.window_handles if window != current][0]
browser.switch_to.window(newWindow)
browser.get_screenshot_as_file(path_to_file)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome. Mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem

Comment: Andersson, Thank you! One more question. Tell me please. How to make it work through a proxy in PhantomJS in the script?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python

Comment: Thank you! I made this worked with: service_args = [
    '--proxy=78.23.244.145:80',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    ]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)

Comment: Can i use list proxy? That there was a list of proxies and the script is worked on all proxies in the list?

Comment: Have no idea :) You might need to open new ticket with this question