# Configure proxy settings Selenium Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

I've been trying for about 2 days to use selenium with a proxy server but have still not been able to do it. I have tried the method from the selenium website, copy and pasting but it didn't work. I've tried all of the answers from Stackoverflow but none of them worked, the closest I got was loading the page but my IP stayed the same.

Here is the code I tried most recently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities



HOST = "144.217.31.225"
PORT = "3128"
def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
        print PROXY_PORT
        print PROXY_HOST
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whater_useragent")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

browser = my_proxy(HOST,PORT)
browser.get('https://www.google.com')

search=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
search.send_keys('my ip')
```

This is the error I received:

```
3128
144.217.31.225
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 32, in <module>
    search=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 313, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/matt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@title='Search']
```

It manages to load the page but fails to enter the text in the search bar. I manually take over and type 'my IP' in the search bar but the IP hasn't changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python

Comment: I tried that one

Comment: you error tells just selenium couldn't find element, you should wait until it loads, with `sleep(5) ` for example. try add  this parameters          `("network.proxy.ssl", proxyHost)
("network.proxy.ssl_port", proxyPort)` because you connecting to https

Comment: your problem is not related to proxy or is it?

Comment: @SAZ Thanks that did it, or though Google had a fit thinking I was a robot, which I guess is true.

Answer (score 2):

This following code worked, or though google didn't like the fact I was using a proxy with selenium, this is why I changed the address to `whatsmyipaddress.com`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from time import sleep


HOST = "144.217.31.225"
PORT = "3128"
def my_proxy(PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT):
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        # Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
        print PROXY_PORT
        print PROXY_HOST
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
        fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override","whater_useragent")
        fp.update_preferences()
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)



browser = my_proxy(HOST,PORT)
browser.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com/')

sleep(5)

search=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Search']")
search.send_keys('my ip')
```

Thanks to @SAZ for the solution.