# Can not connect to the Service geckodriver. Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium with Python3. Here's my code:

```
import socks
import socket
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

opts = Options()
opts.set_headless()
assert opts.headless
browser = Firefox(options=opts)

browser.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
browser.save_screenshot('ip.png')
```

I receive

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not
>   connect to the Service geckodriver

on the line

```
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
```

Problem in the following lines:

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

If I remove them, code work normally. Why does it happens? How should I fix that?

Comment: see if this helps https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python

Comment: I think ` fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
        fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))  ` lines are missing in your code which links actual proxy settings with firefox browser. please refer to this answer which have socks reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567191/2575259