# Setting proxy to selenoid webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, proxy, selenoid

I connect to a selenoid container with web driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
proxy = 'proxy address'
link = '2ip.ru'

capabilities = {
            "browserName": 'firefox',
            "version": '71.0',
            "platform": 'LINUX'
        }
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = proxy
prox.ssl_proxy = proxy
prox.socks_proxy = proxy
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=capabilities
        )
driver.get(link)
```

Getting page with any proxy have same IP in 2ip.ru or any websites like this. Why does selenoid not apply proxy IP?
Tried images selenoid/firefox:60.0, selenoid/firefox:61.0, selenoid/firefox:62.0, selenoid/firefox:70.0, selenoid/firefox:71.0, selenoid/firefox:72.0.

Comment: Just pass proxy capabilities as regular JSON object fields:

capabilities['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}

Comment: It says me 
`exception Message: Invalid proxy configuration entry: autodetect`

Comment: Ok, remove class and autodetect fields. Should only use fields described in spec. https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#proxy

Comment: WIth `capabilities['proxy'] = { "httpProxy":proxy, "ftpProxy":proxy, "sslProxy":proxy, "noProxy":None, "proxyType":"MANUAL" }` I get `exception Message: noProxy is not an array: null`

Comment: With `capabilities['proxy'] = { "httpProxy":proxy, "ftpProxy":proxy, "sslProxy":proxy, "proxyType":"MANUAL" }` I get `Stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5 UnknownError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:483:5 handleReadyState@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:271:21 handleEvent@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:239:9`

Comment: With `capabilities['proxy'] = { "httpProxy":proxy, "proxyType":"MANUAL" }` it works without errors, but doesn't apply proxy ip

Answer (score 0):

Working method with Chrome and Selenoid. This tested on MacOS, but python code in steps 2,3 is universal, so this works on Windows too if Selenoid is correctly working in Docker on your machine

### 1. Prepare selenoid

1. Start Docker (I use docker desktop for MacOS)
2. Start Selenoid (I use Configuration Manager - cm_darwin_amd64
   for macOS, docs: https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_start_selenoid)

   ```py
   # to start selenoid from python code using Jupyter Notebook
   import os
   os.system("selenoid/cm_darwin_amd64 selenoid start")
   ```
3. Start Selenoid-UI (I use port 8081, default is 8080)

   ```py
   os.system("selenoid/cm_darwin_amd64 selenoid-ui start --port 8081")
   ```
4. Check containers working:

   4.1. Selenoid at http://localhost:4444

   4.2. Selenoid-UI at http://localhost:8081/

[image: Selenoid in Docker]

### 2. Prepare selenium and proxy with auth

Running Selenium webdriver in Remote browser using Selenoid is similar to running on your machine local driver so I use proxy for Chrome from my previous case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73744426/5379091 (big topic about selenium proxy, it may be useful)

Now set creds of proxy and define function to fast creating driver

```
import zipfile

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

proxy_param = (<host>, <port>, <user>, <pwd>)  # set creds here

manifest_json = """
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
    }
    """

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % proxy_param

SELENOID_URL="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
SELENOID_WEB_URL="http://localhost:8081"


def get_selenoid_driver():
    
    # enable VNC, choose version
    capabilities = {
        "selenoid:options": {
            "browserName": 'chrome',
            "version": '120.0',
            "enableVNC": True,
            "enableJS": True,
            "enableVideo": False,
            "screenResolution": "1920x1080x24",  # 1280x1024x24
            "sessionTimeout": "3m",
        }
    }
    
    # enable proxy
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'
    with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
        zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
        zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
    chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    
    
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=SELENOID_URL,
        options=chrome_options,
        desired_capabilities=capabilities,
    )
    
    # wait for the page load no matter what (if need it)
    # driver.implicitly_wait(10)  

    print(f"You can view all running drivers here: {SELENOID_WEB_URL}")
    print(f"Direct link to VNC: {SELENOID_WEB_URL}/#/sessions/{driver.session_id}")
    return driver
```

### 3. Run selenium driver using Selenoid

1. Create driver

   ```py
   driver = get_selenoid_driver()
   # You can view all running drivers here: http://localhost:8081
   # Direct link to VNC: http://localhost:8081/#/sessions/<your-session-id>
   ```
2. Check it on Selenoid UI http://localhost:8081

   [image: Selenoid UI - All active drivers]

   Correct VNC in Chrome looks like this

   [image: Example of Chrome driver with VNC]
3. Check proxy is working

   ```py
   url_to_open='https://ifconfig.me'

   driver.get(url_to_open)
   html = driver.page_source

   print(proxy_param[0] in html)
   # True
   ```

   [image: This ip is proxy ip :)]

   This is proxy ip. Success

Links that help me:

1. https://okhlopkov.com/how-to-parse-any-website/ (Idea of using Selenoid)
2. https://aerokube.com/cm/latest/ (Configuration Manager - for install Selenoid, Docker required)
3. https://aerokube.com/selenoid/1.4.3/ (Docs for tuning selenoid)
4. [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python/73744426) (Proxy for selenium python)