# Is there any way to fix "No internet connection please check proxy server" when using seleniumwire and proxies?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am using selenium wire to add proxies to my selenium browser in the following code.

```py
def Proxy():
    global options
    with open ('proxies.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split("\n")
        split_proxies = [line.split(":") for line in lines]
        proxies = [{'https:': f"https://{p[2]}:{p[3]}@{p[0]}:{p[1]}"} for p in split_proxies]
        #proxies = [{'http:':f"http://{p[2]}:{p[3]}@{p[0]}:{p[1]}",'https:':f"https://{p[2]}:{p[3]}@{p[0]}:{p[1]}"} for p in split_proxies]
        options = {
            'proxy': random.choice(proxies)
            }
        print(options)
        


def Login():
    PATH = 'C:\\Users\\royce\\Desktop\\instamoni\\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, seleniumwire_options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
```

I have tested and my proxies are working and alive and everything seems fine with them. When selenium opens the page the first page loads but says `Not secure connection` even though it is a https site. Then if i try search for something or do anything it just says `No internet`. In terminal I also get thrown this errror:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:10950/devtools/browser/30122db5-a37d-40d4-8113-f0314768cb6c
[6732:2536:0101/175116.734:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:51:16.734] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not 
functioning. (0x1F)
[6732:2536:0101/175116.735:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:51:16.734] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not 
functioning. (0x1F)
[6732:2536:0101/175116.736:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [17:51:16.735] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not 
functioning. (0x1F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't configure ssl proxy attribute. Please, refer to [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python) how to configure proxy properly

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
```