# Python & Selenium Proxy Support Using Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I have a proxy that looks like so:
ca-static-2.resdleafproxies.com:11054:167333+CA+167336-351122:t5flrtgkyqtwatw
(This isn't an actual working proxy I've changed parts of it lol)

Is there a way I can use chrome via selenium in python and use this proxy / ones with similar formatting, currently haven't found anything about this type of proxy. TIA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ProxyManager** module:

```
from proxymanager import ProxyManager

proxy_manager = ProxyManager('proxies.txt')

random_proxy = proxy_manager.random_proxy()
```

You can find documenation [here.](https://pypi.org/project/proxy-manager/)

Comment: what do i then do with random_proxy ?

Comment: It randomizes the proxy list