# Python Selenium Proxy Network

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

### Overview

I am using a proxy network and want to configure it with Selenium on Python. I have seen many post use the `HOST:PORT` method, but proxy networks uses the **"URL method" of** `http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT`

### SeleniumWire

I found **SeleniumWire to be a way to connect the "URL method"** of proxy networks to a Selenium Scraper. See basic SeleniumWire configuration:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
    'proxy':
    {
        'http': 'http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT',
        'https': 'http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT'
    },
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options)
driver.get("https://some_url.com")
```

This **correctly adds and cycles a proxy to the driver**, *however* on many websites the **scraper is quickly blocked** by CloudFlare. This blocking is something that does not happen when running on Local IP. After searching through SeleniumWire's GitHub Repository [Issues](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/489), I found that this is caused by TLS fingerprinting and that there is **no current solution** to this issue.[image]

### Selenium Options

I tried to configure proxies the conventional selenium way:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY:PORT")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://some_url.com")
```

A browser **instance does open but fails because of a network error**. Browser instance *does not* load in established URL.

### [image][image]
Docker Configuration

The end result of this configuration would be running python code **within a docker container** that is **within a Lambda function**. Don't know whether or not that introduces a new level of abstraction or not.

### Summary

What other resources can I use to correctly configure my Selenium scraper to use the "URL method" of IP cycling?

### Versions

- python 3.9
- selenium 3.141.0
- docker 20.10.11

### Support Tickets

Github: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10605

ChromeDriver: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Selenium Extension:

A proxy network, or "URL" proxy, can be **configured with Selenium as an extension**. Create the following JS script and JSON file:

### JS script ("background.js")

```
var config = {
mode: "fixed_servers",
rules: {
singleProxy: {
scheme: "http",
host: "<PROXY>",
port: parseInt(<PORT>)
},
bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
}
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});
function callbackFn(details) {
return {
authCredentials: {
username: "<USER>",
password: "<PASSWORD>"
}
};
}
 
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
callbackFn,
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
['blocking']
);
```

### JSON File ("manifest.json")

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
```

---

**Zip background.js and manifest.json as proxy.zip** and write the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension("proxy.zip")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/")
```

Comment: May I know how to modify it if my proxy url does't need a username and password ?

Comment: This is for proxy networks specifically, if you simply have a host:port endpoint it's much easier to configure. There is a lot of support for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing 8 month old accepted answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32550170)