# How do I avoid imperva bot detection?

Tags: python, selenium, imperva

I am running a Python script that scrapes a website. It uses Imperva to detect automated scripts crawling through it's web pages. Imperva has blocked my IP from accessing the site as soon as I run the script. I did read someone suggest including a `time.sleep(random.randint(a,b))` (to try and mimic human behaviour) in the script which it didn't work or perhaps it just wouldn't work as a standalone method. If it's the chrome driver itself that they detect then I guess it would be impossible to avoid. Does anyone have any practical suggestions on things that I could include in my script to bypass this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

There are many different components that need to be added to a web scraper to make it undetectable. I recommend using the below code to **test your current level of detection**:

```
driver.get("https://bot.sannysoft.com/")
```

More than likely, you will **fail most of those tests right off the bat**, fortunately, it's easy to configure a scraper that will pass all of those tests and be completely undetectable.

### Selenium-Stealth

[selenium-stealth](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-stealth/) is a python package that is used to avoid detection. Simply...

```
pip install selenium-stealth
```

and follow the below configuration:

```
stealth(driver,
        user_agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36',
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )
```

Your web scraper **should pass all of the tests**, now *try to implement this solution on the Imperva site.*

### More information

If you are still getting blocked, I recommend looking into the [random-user-agent library](https://pypi.org/project/random-user-agent/) to cycle your user agent within the "user_agent" variable of the selenium-stealth configuration. Otherwise, you could **pay for a proxy provider** to completely disguise your IP. Although keep in mind, **proxy networks currently do not** have a selenium configuration.

***Information on Proxy Network Selenium Configuration:*** [Python Selenium Proxy Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806778/python-selenium-proxy-network)

***Information on Selenium Detectability in the Cloud:*** [Python Selenium AWS Lambda Change WebGL Vendor/Renderer For Undetectable Headless Scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265306/python-selenium-aws-lambda-change-webgl-vendor-renderer-for-undetectable-headles)

Comment: I've never heard of selenium-stealth before. Kudos for bringing that up!.

Comment: Did selenium stealth work for you? Me not.

Comment: As an alternative, you can try undetected-chromedriver.

Comment: selenium-stealth doesn't do anything which leads me to believe that might be some extra bit of work if you already blacklisted...

Comment: @AlexZubkov I would recommend proxy cycling then. Sounds like they blacklisted your IP

Comment: @LukeHamilton yep, selenium-wire library with socks5 proxy does the trick!