# Seleniumwire.py throwing ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED when using Proxies

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, proxies, seleniumwire

I have been trying to add authenticated proxies to my selenium code. I came across selenium wire after alot of research. When I ran the can it threw me this error?

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: headless chrome=102.0.5005.115)
```

```html
import seleniumwire
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

options = {
        'proxy': {
            'https': 'https://proxy.proxyverse.io:443', 
            'http': 'http://proxy.proxyverse.io:443',
        }  
    }

# other chrome options
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
op.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
op.add_argument("--headless") 
op.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
op.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/chromedriver.exe" ,options=op,seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

I need to know what is causing this because without proxies the driver is working fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### SeleniumWire with Proxy Network:

I would not recommend SeleniumWire as there is an *unresolved* [issue with the TLS fingerprint](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/215) and the driver will be **quickly detected by CloudFlare**. The normal Selenium package has a method of proxy configuration but it only works with "host:port" proxies:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.ssl_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

The above configuration *does NOT* work with the proxy network endpoint method ("https://proxy.proxyverse.io:443") and there seems to be no current solution.

---

*For more detail* and current tracking: [Python Selenium Proxy Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806778/python-selenium-proxy-network)